# Can't filter categories using isotope

Tags: categories, javascript

I'm trying to initialise isotope https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ in Wordpress so I can start filtering posts based on their categories. I think I'm missing some php in the `<a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a>` section because when i click on the category it gives me a /# instead of filtering the categories. I'm really trying to achieve this filtering effect: https://nmbw.com.au/works-and-projects/

I'm new to this so any help would be really appreciated.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: isotope
 *
 * Template for displaying a page without sidebar even if a sidebar widget is published.
 *
 * @package understrap
 */

get_header();
$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
?>

<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">All categories</a></li>
<?php
$terms = get_terms("category"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
$count = count($terms); //How many are they?
if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
//create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
}
}
?>
</ul>


<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=9' ); //Check the WP_Query docs to see how you can limit which posts to display ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="isotope-list">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );  //Get the terms for this particular item
$termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term
$termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs
}
?>
<div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item">
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                      the_post_thumbnail();
                } ?>
</div> <!-- end item -->
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
    </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is what I have in my functions.php file

```
function add_isotope() {
wp_register_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/libs/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'),  true );
wp_register_script( 'isotope-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.js', array('jquery', 'isotope'),  true );
wp_register_script( 'isotope-custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope-custom.js', array('jquery', 'isotope'),  true );
wp_register_style( 'isotope-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/isotope.css' );

wp_enqueue_script('isotope-init');
wp_enqueue_style('isotope-css');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_isotope' );
```

This is in my isotope-custom.js file

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the 
blog posts
$container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the 
PHP
itemSelector : '.item', 
layoutMode : 'masonry'
});

//Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from 
the others
var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
// don't proceed if already selected
if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
return false;
}
var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
$optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$this.addClass('selected');

//When an item is clicked, sort the items.
var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });

return false;
});

});
```

This is in the isotope.js file
      `jQuery(function ($) {

```
 //set the container that isotope will be inside of in a var

 var container = document.querySelector('#isotope-list');

 //create empty var isotope

 var Isotope;

 // initialize Isotope after all images have loaded
 var $container = $('#isotope-list').imagesLoaded( function() {
 $container.isotope({
 // options
 });
 });




 var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all 
 the blog posts
 $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in 
 the PHP
 itemSelector : '.item',
 layoutMode : 'masonry',
 isOriginLeft: false
 });
 var container = document.querySelector('#isotope-list');
 // init
 var iso = new Isotope( container, {
 // options
 itemSelector: '.item',

 });

 //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from 
 the others
 var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
 $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  // don't proceed if already selected
  if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
  return false;
  }
  var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
  $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $this.addClass('selected');

  //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

  return false;
  });

  });

  jQuery( function($) {

  $('.isotope').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  masonry: {
  columnWidth: 100
  }
  });

  });`
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why do you have a certain expectation about PHP output and what happens differently/unexpectedlyt? This is hard to follow for someone who isn’t familiar with Isotope specifics.

Comment: Hi @Rarst what i assumed turned out to be wrong after running some tests. Isotope allows you to filter categories which is what I'm trying to achieve. Here's their website: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Can you add to your question the javascript code you're using for initialising isotope and also the javascript code for the filters links?

Comment: Hi @dbeja i've just edited my initial post with what im using to initialise isotope

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent the default behaviour of the click event using jQuery right from the beginning:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the 
blog posts
var $isotope = $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the 
PHP
itemSelector : '.item', 
layoutMode : 'masonry'
});

//Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from 
the others
var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
// don't proceed if already selected
if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
return false;
}
var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
$optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$this.addClass('selected');

//When an item is clicked, sort the items.
var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$isotope.isotope({ filter: selector });

return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks @dbeja, that seems to have initialised isotope properly but am now getting `Uncaught TypeError: Isotope is not a constructor` in my Chrome console

Comment: I think it's because $container isn't a isotope element. What if on the top of your script you save the isotope to a new variable var isotope = $container.isotope... And then on the click event of the filter you use instead isotope.isotope...

Comment: Thanks @dbeja. How would I go about doing that? I'm new to web dev! Thanks

Comment: I edit my answer to include all your js code with both modifications (preventDefault and $isotope). See if it helps.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit confused. I've put in that edited js code but I'm still getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Isotope is not a constructor` error

Comment: Do you have any live link?

Comment: I don't unfortunately. I'm working locally

Comment: If you only leave the isotope initialization, do you still get the same error?
`jQuery(function ($) {
 var $container = $('#isotope-list');
 var $isotope = $container.isotope({
  itemSelector : '.item', 
  layoutMode : 'masonry'
 });
});`

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately. I've inspected the code, here is the mark up;
     <ul class="filters'>
     <li>
     <a href="#" data-filter='*" class="selected">everything</a>
     </li>
     <li>
     <a href="#" data-filter=".analysis">analysis</a>
     </li>
     </ul>

Does that help?

Comment: And you still have the wp_enqueue_scripts action on your functions.php, right?

Comment: Yep, still have them on the wp_enqueue_scripts action

Comment: sorry @dbeja i also have a file called isotope.js which i have posted in my original comment

Comment: and where are you loading your isotope-custom.js?

Comment: in functions.php after isotope.js. That wasn't in my original post but have added it in now @dbeja

Comment: And if you comment your isotope-custom.js file, do you still have that error in the console? Just to understand if the problem is only on the custom file or also on the other one.